# IP address of the type 192.168.0.0/16

Tags: ip

I was studying about IP addresses when I came Across an address of type `127.0.0.1/8`. I know that`127.0.0.1` is a loop-back address but what did `/8` mean in the address.what `/8` (in `127.0.0.1/8`) specify

Comment: The answer is here, it's about a mask while processing addresses
http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/the-slash-after-an-ip-address-cidr-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the /8 in your ip is the subnet mask.
It allows you to know on which subnetwork you are, find your broadcast and unicast IP.

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork to have more informations

Answer (score 1):

`/8` is a subnet mask written in CIDR notation and which is used by hosts to determine if they are on the same network as some other host and can communicate directly or they need to use a router (default gateway). In your case this is a loopback address, and actually all IP addresses from 127.0.0.0/8 network (from 127.0.0.0 to 127.255.255.255) are reserved loopback addresses as defined in [rfc6890: Special-Purpose Address Registries](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6890)